# CSS Keyframes Infinite Transform Rotation

Tags: css, css-animations, mobile-website

It is an infinite animation for the mobile menu. It breaks when I go to another page but not always. When I use the Inspector Mode in Chrome and go through the pages it never breaks. On mobile sometimes it just gets bugged and the "transform" property from the @keyframes is not applied but at the same time, all other properties are here.

That is the link - https://athelloworkingg.webflow.io/
That is how it looks when it gets bugged - [Bug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rI0hk.png)

Here is my CSS

```
.navmenu-navlink > span {
transition: all 300ms ease;
}

.navmenu-navlink-mobile:nth-child(odd) {
  animation-name: spinClockwise;
  animation-duration: 90000ms;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: linear; 
}
.navmenu-navlink-mobile:nth-child(even) {
  animation-name: spinAntiClockwise;
  animation-duration: 90000ms;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: linear; }

@keyframes spinClockwise {from {-webkit-transform:rotate(0deg);}to {-webkit-transform:rotate(360deg);}}
@keyframes spinAntiClockwise {from {-webkit-transform:rotate(360deg);}to {-webkit-transform:rotate(0deg);}}
```

I tried using -WebKit- and -moz-, also tried to delay the animation, to play it on document.ready(). I also tried to put as a default state - animation-play-state: paused, then to make it run when you click on the hamburger and to pause it again when you click on one of the menu items.

All these things did not help me. I would be very thankful if someone can assist me with that.

Comment: I got a JS error when using the Edge/Chrome inspector (emulating iPhone SE on a Windows10 laptop) after several clicks on the menu items. Are you seeing any errors on the inspect facility console? Are you able to extract just enough code to make a minimal runnable snippet? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @AHaworth It does not give me any error when it happens. It happens when I click on some page from the menu. And when I am there instead of loading all properties that I set. It loads only only  position: absolute; bottom: auto; left: 50%; transform-origin: center 0.638625em;. We are missing only     transform: translateX(-0.466504em) rotate(-173.766deg); which comes from the keyframes. I was thinking of adding translate to the keyframes but I cannot calculate it so it goes automatically rotation from 0 to 360

Comment: That’s weird. I see the. Error when clicking on the revolving Contact sometimes, and that results in all the characters overlaying each other as in the picture you provided. I would suspect a timing issue but can’t understand how you don’t see the error.

Comment: @AHaworth Thanks a lot for telling me what is the issue. I tried to put animation delay but it did not work :/ What would you suggest me?

Comment: Have a really close look at the code for the contact page. It looks as though it is trying to use the $ of jquery just before the jquery js is loaded. That is the error I saw.